# Cordova build for android fails with silly escape error

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I'm getting a really silly error when building my cordova app. Building the app has been working until I installed the facebook connect plugin.

The error is as follows:

```
facebookconnect.xml:6: error: Apostrophe not preceded by \ (in 'secretapp')
```

While the error speaks for itself, I can't fix it.

My facebookconnect.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<resources>
    <string name="fb_app_id">149914046366xxxx</string>
    <string name="fb_app_name">secretapp</string>
    <string name="fb_app_id">'149914046366xxxx'</string>
    <string name="fb_app_name">'secretapp'</string>
</resources>
```

Now if I try to escape the apostrophes i.e. \', or remove the apostrophes, when I run the build it will paste two additional lines into this xml without the () escape character again and hence throw the same error.

So the question is, what is the source of these strings that are being inserted? I checked through all my files I could think of (plugin.xml, strings.xml), removed the apostrophe wherever possible, but it still comes back into the facebookconnect.xml.

Any suggestions where this could be coming from?

Comment: found the issue. android.json file had the apostrophes that was used to populate the xml.